# Does this code indicate an exploit?

Tags: security, nonce

I have just started seeing this code on a single Page on our site. This Page is assigned as the static home page for the site.

```
<input name="_wp_http_referer" value="/" type="hidden">
<input id="send" name="send" value="70630a2369" type="hidden">
```

It is appearing just before the content() is rendered for page.php. ie.

```
<?php the_content('<div class="post-more">Read the rest of this entry &raquo;</div>'); ?>
```

I've tried doing a regex scan of the entire list of php and js files (theme, core and plug-ins) and can't locate where it's being generated.

Answer (score 1):

The `_wp_http_referer` field is generated by [the `wp_referer_field()` function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_referer_field). I'm not familiar with the hidden `send` field - however, I'd wager it's [a nonce](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces') field.

In all likelihood this pair of hidden inputs was generated by a call to [the `wp_nonce_field()` function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_field) with `'send'` as the `$name` argument and the `$referer` argument set to `true`. These fields are a component of good plugin security practices, and aide in verifying the authenticity of user interactions.

In your case, the call is likely executed directly in a template file, or a theme or a plugin logic file in a function attached to the [`the_content` filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) - though it could also be called in a shortcode, or numerous other action/filter hooks.

While malicious code might still leverage good security practices, the presence of such practices by itself is in no way indicative of exploitation.

Comment: Other than brute force (disabling every plug-in, then searching for hooks as you suggest, is there a way I can trace it back to where it was generated from?

Comment: Not in particular... ultimately close inspection is the easiest way... If you're not using any shortcodes or plugin-generated forms on the pages on which the inputs appear, I'd reckon it's a `'the_content'` filter hook. Instead of searching for the hook, though, you may want to take a stab at searching your *wp_content* directory for `wp_nonce_field\(\s*[^,]*,\s*['"]send['"]`. Failing that, `add_filter\(\s*["']the_content["']` should turn up all `'the_content'` filters (unless they're registered with 'the_content' in a variable, of course) - you'd then need to inspect each's logic

Comment: Instead of manually searching for hooks, the [Debug Bar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/) plugin with the [Actions & Filters Addon](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar-actions-and-filters-addon) can prove useful when exploring what actions and filters executed on a page, and which callbacks were attached to them.